# Не открывает порты на Windows

Tags: ip, порты, порт, сканирование-портов

У меня внешний ИП, я его отдельно подключил услугой, мне необходимо пробросить порты и для этого я создал правила в своем роутере:

- https://prnt.sc/QsSNQ4pjxqgp
- https://prnt.sc/a4MloTp2cXg4

Когда начал тестировать оказалось что они закрыты, вспомнил про фаервол, пошел туда создал правила на эти порты (https://prnt.sc/9g97lVNby8sK) на входящий и исходящий соответственно и вот тут самое интересное, они всё еще закрыты, тестирую локальные порты с помощью команды telnet  и вот тут я совсем не могу понять правила для открытия есть но они закрыты локально, пробовал отключать брандмауэр и кидал его на заводские - не помогло (https://prnt.sc/MuFyE0FLZMnD)

Так же я прописал статику для пк и сделал привязку ИП по маку, отключил межсетевой экран  SPI

подскажите в чем может быть беда(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порт "открывается" только тогда, когда его слушает какая-то программа. А какую программу вы запустили на портах `3389`, `3390`, `80` и `443`?

Вы настроили перенаправление порта. Это правильно, но нужно что-нибудь запустить на этом порте, чтобы всё работало.

Процесс выглядит так: допустим на вашем компьютере крутится майнкрафт сервер (порт `25565`). И я хочу к нему подключиться, вы даете мне ip (например `125.112.52.26`, я ввожу `125.112.52.26:25565` И ничего не работает. Почему?

Потому что `125.112.52.26` это IP вашей сети. То есть IP вашего роутера. Ваш компьютер не подключается к интернету напрямую, на самом деле вы подключаетесь к роутеру, а он отправляет ваши запросы в интернет. После получения ответа ваш роутер отправляет его в ваш компьютер, и вы видите страницу в бразуере.

Теперь представим, что я хочу подключиться к вашему майнкрафт серверу. Пишу ваш IP, подключаюсь. Запрос приходит в ваш роутер, но обрабатывать то его должен ваш компьютер с сервером Майнкрафта.

Мой запрос дошел до роутера, а роутер не знает, куда он предназначается. Поэтому мой запрос не обработан, и я получу ошибку подключения.

Вот здесь то и приходит на помощь **перенаправление портов** (то, что вы делали в роутере). Задание таких правил как бы говорит роутеру: "Братишка, если пришел запрос на порт `25565`, передай его именно на мой компьютер с локальным IP `192.168.0.103`, это ко мне пришли." И теперь, когда я опять попытаюсь подключиться к вашему серверу, роутер посмотрит: "Так, запрос на порт `25565`, ну-ка ну-ка, О! Этого нужно направить вот на тот компьютер с локальным IP `192.168.0.103`", передаст запрос вам на компьютер, а программа, которая запущена на вашем помпьютере и отвечает за работу майнкрафт сервера, посмотрит, что на `25565` порт пришел запрос, обработает его, и вернет мне ответ.

Что же будет, если майнкрафт сервер вы не запустите?

Роутер посмотрит, что запрос нужно отправить на ваш компьютер, что он и сделает. Итак запрос пришел на ваш компьютер, а кто его обработает? Операционная система увидит, что порт 25565 никакая программа не слушает, подумает, что я ошибся адресом, и опять же, я увижу ошибку подключения.

**Поэтому ваши порты автоматически откроются при запуске программы, которая будет их прослушивать.**

Тогда причем же здесь брендмауэр? Брэндмауэр может быть настроен так, что к порту `25565` по его мнению, подключаться никому будет нельзя. Поэтому ещё до момента, когда ваш майнкрафт сервер мне ответит, брендмауэр запретит мне подключение.

Ещё один вопрос, котроый может у вас быть: "А как же тогда я получаю ответы на запросы к сайтам?" Такие запросы выполняются на портах `80` и `443`. Которые вроде никто никогда не открывал. Как так? Все очень просто, запросы к интернету вы делаете **САМИ**.

Если упростить, то выглядит это так: Вы вводите в браузере `https://ru.stackoverflow.com`. Ваш компютер шлет запрос в роутер, как бы говоря, "братишка, а можешь мне показать вот этот сайт?", роутер отправялет запрос в интернет, там провайдер находит сайт, передает запрос к сайту, сайт отправляет какой-то результат (например главную страницу). Его ответ отправляется назад к вам. Приходит в роутер. Роутер помнит, что это именно вы спрашивали этот сайт, и поэтому результат он отдает именно на ваш компьютер. а браузер вам его показывает.

В то время как перенаправление `80` и `443` порта в роутере нужно, если вы хотите, чтобы ваш компьютер САМ отдавал в интернет например какой-то сайт. Обычно для этого используются программы типа `nginx` или `apache`. Но бывают и другие.

Так же, у совсем неопытных читателей может возникнуть вопрос: "Ну вот vk.com, например, он сразу оповещает меня о новых сообщениях, значит он все-таки сам шлет мне информацию о новых сообщениях, хотя я ничего не открывал?"

На самом деле это не так. Ваш браузер не слушает ВК, пока он сам вам не скажет, что пришли новые сообщения. Вместо этого браузер каждую секунду САМ спрашивает у ВК "А не пришли ли мне новые сообщения"? Что работает по тому же принципу, что в примере со `stackoverflow.com` выше, только в фоновом режиме.

Как итог, мой ответ таков: Всё выглядит правильным, но вы запустили программу, которая должна прослушивать порты `3389` и `3390`?

Comment: Очень развернуто и доходчиво рассказано, за это большое спасибо. На портах 3389 и 3390 я развернул РДП подключение к ПК, собсно это сервак. Я кажись понял в чем именно у меня беда, в случае какого-нибудь результата я отпишу. Но вот у меня один вопрос если на том же 2ip проверить порты на доступность то пишет что они закрыты, это выходит не так?
и еще вопрос по команде телнет, она же локально проверяет порт и посылает запрос разве порт не должен сказать что он открыт? или 100% на этом порте должна крутиться прога для положительного ответа?

Comment: 100% Должна крутиться прога. Порт ничего не говорит, это прога говорит: "да, да, я на этом порте работаю, жду запросов. давай давай." А про 2ip: Я не знаю, разрешает ли RDP такую проверку, возможно оно не отвечает на запросы 2ip. Так же проверьте, может у вас сменился локальный ip адрес при переподключении к роутеру (например при перезагрузке ПК). Это нужно отдельно настраивать, чтобы IP всегда был одинаковым

Comment: Спасибо Вам больше. Оказывается, я все правильно делал но закопался и зациклился именно на закрытых портах. Ваше утверждение о 100% работающей программе подтолкнуло дальше доделать пару процессов и это заработало. Ещё раз огромное спасибо за объяснение развернутое и помощь, Вы очень сильно помогли)