Настройка фтп на локальном компьютере с серым ip
от чего не работает доступ с компьютеру извне и не пробрасываются порты роутера тплинк? В тплинк настроил 21-й порт, айпи компа, где активировал фтп средствами винды7, но локально (файлзиллой) могу зайти в папку, а извне нет.

В браузере тоже не открывается ни локалхост ни имя папки ни айпи (доступ запрещён или просто невозможно отобразить страницу).

Использовал noip ddns тк мобильный интернет и серый айпи. Вроде всё по мануалам из гугла, а нет доступа хоть тресни....


Прочитал этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1427495/553632 (вроде всё понятно, но не работает (((  )
Несколько раз пересоздавал фтп, группу, пользователей. В тплинке дднс отображается как успешное подключение...

ddns не создаст вам белый айпи каким-то магическим образом

Так гугл говорит, что для доступа извне как раз дднс и нужен, обращение идет по имени, зарегистрированному на том сервисе, и он уже обращается по непосредственному айпи роутера, действительному на текущий момент. Разве нет? Что делаю не так?

«по непосредственному айпи роутера» — который должен быть не серым, ага

ну я не в курсе, чем они отличаются толком... Увидел про дднс, думал поможет, а получается, что толку от этих дднс как от козла.... (( Если вбить на сервисе дднс реальный айпи который в роутере - фтп работает, а вот тот айпи, который провайдер передаёт реально в сервисы - фиг.
